# Excel VBA specify sort range by numbers for cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

The code below does what I want (sort data by the value in column K)....

```
    Range(TestSheet.Cells(2, 1), TestSheet.Cells(30, 11)).Sort Key1:=Range("K1"), _
                                                          Order1:=xlAscending, _
                                                          Header:=xlNo
```

... but I want to generalize the whole thing, replacing the numbers variables etc.
I can't, however, figure out how to set the sort key range using numbers instead of the cell reference "K1". I would have thought I could do something like....

```
    Range(TestBOMSheet.Cells(2, 1), TestBOMSheet.Cells(30, 11)).Sort Key1:=Range(TestBOMSheet.Cells(2, 11)), _
                                                          Order1:=xlAscending, _
                                                          Header:=xlNo
```

...but have tried various and always get a syntax error.

Comment: `Key1:=TestBOMSheet.Cells(2, 11)`.